# adding new field to to my html page using JS and checking for auto complete in .XML.PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, xml

> want to add one more auto-complete input field i have no ides how to
>   do it. adding new field to to my html page using JS and checking for
>   auto complete in .XML.PHP file
>
> this is my .js file

```
        (function(){
      var WINDOW=window,
      DOCUMENT=document,
      SCAN=gui.app.scan,
      SYS=gui.system,
      U=gui.util,
      D=gui.dom,
      E=gui.event,
      W=gui.widget,

      form,
      formname='gblForm-Unit',
      autos={},
      reqd={
        fields:['unitId'],
        types:{
          'unitId':'alphanum'
        }
      };

      /**
       * Set a field as required if it exists
       * @private
       * @param {String} id ID of the field
       * @returns {Void}
       */
      function setRequired(id){
        if (D.get(id)){
          reqd.fields.push(id);
        }
      }
```

> Handles the onLoad event for the window

```
      function onload(){
        if (SCAN.ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT){
          if (D.get('#'+ formname)){
            setRequired('unitId');

            form=new U.FormSubmit(formname, reqd, ws.error.getFormError);
            form.registerScanningField('unitId');
            form.registerButton([
              { id:'gblBtn-Submit', type:'submit' }
            ]);
          }
          }
         }

          E.add(WINDOW, 'load', onload);
         }());
```

> ```
> this is my .xml.php page
> ```

```
      <?php
       try {
        $unitId=ws::scrub(@$_GET['unitId'], 'alphanum');

        $xml = new wsResultDocument();
        $data = $xml->getNodeSet('data');

        if ($unitId){
            $unit = wsModel::execSP('GetUnit', array('data' => $unitId));

            if (!sizeof($unit)){
                throw new UserException('UNIT_VALUE_INVALID', $unitId);
            }

            $groups = array(
                array(
                    'column'    => 'UNMT_Serial',
                    'table' => 'UNMT',
                    'nodeName'  => 'unit',
                ),
                array(
                    'column'    => 'UTDT_Label',
                    'table' => 'UTDT',
                    'groupName' => 'values',
                    'nodeName'  => 'value',
                ),
            );

            $data->addNodeSet(wsResult::groupedNodeSet($unit, $groups, null, false));
        }
      }
      catch(Exception $e){
        wsError::logException($e);
        $xml = wsError::exceptionToResult($e);
    }

    return $xml;
    ?>
```